# Foreground for Flash games

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage

I've noticed that most Flash games (and other SWFs) have `foregrounds` incorporated into them. The reason being to cover up graphic you're not supposed to see upon entering full screen (graphic outside the boundaries of the `stage`).

The `foreground` is simply a piece of graphic with a stage-sized hole in the middle, where the `stage` will show through. (Or that is what it seems to be, anyway).

What would be the simplest way to incorporate something like this into a Flash game? (In terms of highest `childIndex` etc). All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking is the best solution for this. You have to simply create a shape (rectangle or even circle or a complex set of drawing) and then setting it as mask. Then The masked viewport only shows the area of the mask's shape.

Take a look at this
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/

Comment: Works great and seems like the simplest solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.addChildAt(myMC,stage.numChildren-2);
```

This will add `myMC` to the stage at the z level that is just below the highest z-order (which should be where you put your border).

To explain further, `numChildren` returns the number of children that the `DisplayObject` it is called on has.  But remember, the z-order index is "zero based" which means that if the parent display object has 12 children, the `numChildren` method will return 12, but the highest z-order index will be 11 and the first will be 0.  So the highest z-order child will have an index of 'numChildren-1`(this could be where the mask/border) and the highest level below that would be`numChildren-2`.